# How to divide angular application base on user role?

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading, lazy-initialization

Let's assume we have classic mvc server application. There are 3 roles (admin, user, spectator) - admin get's access to 90%, user and spectator 10%. In classic app views are generated on the server side, so user and sepectator ends with exacly 10% of app designed for them.

Now if we were to rewrite this app as a single page app in angular. For many reasons user and spectator should not be serve with whole app. What options are there? I thought about:

1. dividing this into 3 single page apps with some shared code (but it can be a problem if you require to serv it as one app from the same address)
2. Using some lazy load technics to load "proper application" - this would require to put loading logic directly into application, and possibly make build process much harder (as you end up with 3 in 1 app)

Are there any other choices / ways ?
What lazy load libs / solutions work well with angular ?

Comment: "for many reasons" - name a few, please

Comment: it could be: 1) size, 2) loading time, 3) memory usage 4) security and i think in general it is good to deliver only relevant and needed data

Comment: 1) size shoudn't be too much important - speaking only about pure javascript (which should be minimized and compressed and cached). Reasons 2 & 3 are basically the same as 1. 4) nothing related to security

Comment: Maybe there is context when size will be important like high traffic. Memory usage can be an issue for mobile environment. Yes 2,3 are derivatives of size.

Comment: App is minimized and templates are concatenated into one file. I want to know if there are some ways to do that, and how or if it is a thing from server side world which just don't work in angular single page apps.

Comment: You can load a different js app after login, there's no problem there but I would be better to optimize once you know there is really a problem, not because of theoretic problems.